# I want to insert a list of at least 500 records into an phoenix table through an sql query from scala code. Is there a way to do this?

Tags: sql, scala, sql-insert, apache-phoenix

I want to insert a list of at least 500 records into a phoenix table through an sql query. But doing it in the following way will make the sql query way too big:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_list)
VALUES
(value_list_1),
(value_list_2),
...
(value_list_n);
```

Is there a way to insert a list of records directly? I am coding in scala.

Comment: From where are you inserting?

Comment: @JimMacaulay I read the data from an excel sheet, i have it in a scala list now